# Playing sound in Java using java.applet class

Tags: java, swing

I am building a simple program with one button. I want to play the "zvuk.wav" file after I click on the button. It's not working though and I cant solve why. When I click the button, nothing happens. The zvuk.wav file is in the src file with the classes.

**Here is my first class which imports java.applet:**

```
    package Music;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.applet.*;


public class Music {

     private URL soubor;

        public Music(String cesta){
           try {
                soubor = new URL("file:"+cesta);
            } catch (MalformedURLException vyjimka) {
                System.err.println(vyjimka);
            }
            Applet.newAudioClip(soubor).play();
        }


}
```

**MainFram which extends JFrame and has one Button:**

```
package Music;


import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class MainFrame extends JFrame{

public static final int WIDTH = 480;
public static final int HEIGHT = 600;

private String file;



public MainFrame(){
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    setTitle("Přehrávač");
    setResizable(false);

    JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
    JButton bPlay = new JButton("PLAY");


    jPanel.setLayout(null);
    add(jPanel);
    jPanel.add(bPlay);
    bPlay.setBounds(200, 250, 100, 50);


    bPlay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Music music = new Music("zvuk.wav");

        }
    });

}




public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new MainFrame();
        }
    });
}


}
```

Comment: Please give us more details about how it is not working. Do you get an error, or does it run but nothing happens? If its an error then please edit your question and add it. Also where is 'zvuk.wav' stored?

Comment: The frame opens with the button. If i click the button, nothing happens though. The zvuk.wav is stored in the src file of the workspace. @sorifiend

Comment: Not sure if its a mistake, but you are missing `import java.applet.AudioClip;` in your Music applet

Comment: well, if it was a problem, eclipse would throw an error, wouldn't it? @sorifiend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that `Applet.newAudioClip(url).play()` does not throw an error if it fails for whatever reason (for example nothing will happen if the project cannot find the wav file).

Try this stand alone test app. Does it work?

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      URL url = new URL("file:zvuk.wav" );
      AudioClip ac = Applet.newAudioClip(url);
      ac.play();

      System.out.println("Press any key to exit.");
      System.in.read();
      ac.stop();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```

If this small sample works, then it should be a small matter to modify it for your purposes.

However if it doesn't work then we almost certainly know that you project is unable to find the wav file.

Try add this to the code above:

```
//existing line
URL url = new URL("file:zvuk.wav" );
//new lines to debug wav file location
File myMusicFile = new File(url.getPath());
if(myMusicFile.exists() && !myMusicFile.isDirectory()) { 
    System.out.println("File exists and is not a directory");
}
```

If the file does not exist then that's your problem, and you need to point your URL to the correct location.

However if the file does exist and it still doesn't work then we have another possible issue outside of code.

- It is possible that `.play()` is completing too quickly, see below for an example of how to keep it alive.
- It is possible that your wav file is not a type that can be played, or it requires an unsupported codec. This is a far bigger topic and needs a new question, and a little bit of research on your part.

Here is the example to keep it alive from the sample code:

```
//load and start audio
AudioClip ac = Applet.newAudioClip(url);
ac.play();

System.out.println("Press any key to exit.");
//keep thread alive until a key is pressed
System.in.read();
ac.stop();
```

---

Sources:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.applet/AppletnewAudioClipURLaudioFileURL.htm

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/AudioClip.html#play%28%29

Comment: Just a quick note to add to this: Try compile your code and run it outside of eclipse and manually ensure that your wav file is in the correct location.

Comment: Answer updated to note that: It is possible that your wav file is not a type that can be played, or it requires an unsupported codec. This is a far bigger topic and needs a new question, and a little bit of research on your part.

Comment: The problem was really in the path of the zvuk.wav file. I just had to take it from src to the project directory.

Comment: @TomášNosek Excellent, I should have guessed that from the start, it is typical with eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I do this using NetBeans. This is the code.

Music.java file

```
package sound.play;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Music {

    private URL soubor;

    public Music(String cesta) {
        try {
            soubor = new URL("file:" + cesta);
        } catch (MalformedURLException vyjimka) {
            System.err.println(vyjimka);
        }
        Applet.newAudioClip(soubor).play();
    }
}
```

MainFram which extends JFrame and has one Button

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public static final int WIDTH = 200;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 200;

    private String file;

    public MainFrame() {
        initComponents();
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setTitle("Přehrávač");
        setResizable(false);

        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();

        jPanel.setLayout(null);
        add(jPanel);

    }

 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        Music music = new Music("zvuk.wav");
        String filename = "zvuk.wav";
        URL url = this.getClass().getResource(filename);
        File myMusicFile = new File(url.getPath());

        AudioClip ac = Applet.newAudioClip(url);
        ac.play();
        System.out.println("Press any key to exit.");
    }                                        

public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```